# Change portion of value within an array knowing only part of string

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

```
$array = array("josh&&3", "mary&&5", "cape&&4", "doggy&&8", etc..);
```

and I know only the string before && which is username.
`$str = "mary&&";` ***Note that I don't know what is after &&***

I want to know whether exist or not within the array, and if exist change the value to something new like `mary&&7`

```
$isExists = preg_match("/$str/", $array);
if ($isExists){
echo "Its exists";
} else {
echo "Not exixts" 
} ;
```

How can I change the portion of the value after && in `mary&&5` or completely change `mary&&5` to `mary&&7` since I don't know before hand the value mary&&5?

Comment: So you want to add 2 to every number in every element? Or just 5 -> 7 ?

Comment: Just change the 5 to 7, no to every element since I want to update the whole array but only in that part of the array mary&&5 to mary&&7 or 3 it doesn't matter the number but the changing on the fly. Step one, I get to know if exist part of the string within the array, say a username that has a value, but I don't know the value, and I want to update the value for that user to a new value I gathered from him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the array and apply the below regex against each item.

```
preg_replace("~(?<=$str&&).*~", '7', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks man, WOW!! I was banging my head the whole freaking day